# JqueryUI Accordion in Responsive Design

Tags: css, jquery-ui, responsive-design, jquery-ui-accordion

I would like to know how best to accomodate the JUI accordian in a responsive design using media queries. It seems that the accordion requires more space than the div that holds it... possibly margin settings?

I ran into this problem when I tried to have two accordions side by side and responsive using media queries

```
#accordionA,
#accordionB { display:block; width:100%; }


/* Double Column breakpoint at 576px */
@media all and (min-width: 36em){ 
            #accordionA { float: left; width:63%; }
            #accordionB { float: left; width:37%; }

        }
```

On a large screen the accordions are not rendered, but are identifiable as elements in the console.

If I reduce the window size they appear, but only at 520px.

I made the change to

```
    #accordionA { float: left; width:55%; }
    #accordionB { float: left; width:30%; }
```

and now I can see both accordions but with some of the screen unused. I could contiue to guesstimate the maximum % i can give to 2 accoridons, but I would prefer to understand what is happening here.

Why, and how much, space does the accordion widget need?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: @Salman, please see my answer as to why I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone creates this same problem for themselves the problem lies not with jquery UI accordion.

Because it is likely that the 2 accordions are of different heights remember to

```
clear: both
```

after them to stop the following div interfering.